# What is a good substitute word for the X-cum-Y construction?

Tags: single-word-requests, offensive-language, latin, euphemisms

I wanted to use the word "cum" to avoid repeating "and" in the following phrase:

> example.com is a teacher-cum-student search and listing site...

But on second thoughts, the word "cum" is also a vulgar slang, which certainly would raise a few eyebrows when readers come across it. Is there a good substitute for this word?

Comment: We appreciate when someone with a question shares their work. What did you find when you looked for synonyms for *and* or *cum* in the dictionary? You did do that, didn't you?

Comment: @medica, am I supposed to be Mr Obvious telling the world that "together, with, including, also, too, besides, furthermore, moreover, etc" are unsuitable synonyms before I can post a question?

Comment: Read the section (in *help*) on how to ask a good question. Yes, that is exactly what you're supposed to do, for two reasons. One is that you don't waste people's time when they suggest words you've already rejected. That's just polite and thoughtful. The second is that we are not a dictionary, and discourage people from using EL&U in that manner. Showing us that you actually *have* looked it up shows some willingness to accommodate the site's requests.

Comment: @medica, normally I would. But, in this case I personally find it too basic for anyone not to know. Anyway thanks for the clarification.

Comment: So example.com is a search and listing site for people who are both teachers and students? That's what the current phrasing says. Quite a narrow target group.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, are you trying to say A-cum-B means an intersection between A and B? You seem to know something more. Can share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Not an intersection, no; but _X-cum-Y_ means ‘an X that is also Y’, not ‘an X and a Y’. _Cum_ means ‘with’, literally, not ‘and’.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure *X-cum-Y* is a substitute for *X and Y*.

*X-cum-Y* means that the single entity A is both an X and a Y at the same time, *X and Y* suggests two entities A being an X and B being a Y, except for the likes of *johnny-cum-lately* which is not the same thing.

If anything I'd think that it's *search and listing* that you want to combine into a dual nature rather than the intended audience and in that case *example.com is a teacher and student search/listing site* might work.

Comment: "except for the likes of johnny-cum-lately which is not the same thing." Ain't that the truth! "Johnny-COME-lately" refers to someone who arrives late to a situation.

Comment: How about `or` instead of `/`? Is there any difference?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow I think _or_ is a bit exclusive as in _search or listing_ when you want it to mean both.

Comment: I think I get your first point after reading Janus's comment. Regarding `or`, I thought it is by default inclusive unless `either` is used?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow The clusivity of _or_ has been discussed [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95624/use-of-or-inclusive-or-exclusive). I suggested that in your case it seems _a bit exclusive_ but that's only my view.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best substitute for 'cum' is the simple forward slash:

*teacher/student search and listing site.*

However, you might also consider encouraging your readers to lift their minds out of the gutter by ignoring the salacious connotations of the word 'cum'.

Similarly, it seems a pity for everybody to have to stop allowing their consciences to prick them or refrain from cheering when someone cocks a snook at overbearing authority -- or for Dick's friends to be compelled to always call him Richard -- simply because they are all terrified of offending some self-styled Savonarola-in-a-suit.

Comment: Careful of the word 'slash'. It is an only slightly less offensive way of saying 'piss' in Britain. Polite people, when giving web addresses say 'stroke'.

Comment: Heh heh, he said 'stroke'

Answer (score 1):

I have been in your shoes, and, yes, it makes you uneasy to use the "cum" word simply to mean "in addition to" when you are familiar with its vulgar aspect.

So, I often use the "plus" word, which essentially means "together with" or "in addition to".

> I am a writer-plus-programmer.

But, to be honest, writer-cum-programmer sounds better.

Comment: "plus" is actually a great suggestion.  I don't like using "cum" or "Re" because it's so faux-intellectual to use latin. Great idea, Calypto.

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks. And, I didn't know about "Re"... good of you to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

I would never worry about using a word which had a legitimate meaning.

'Cum' is simply the Latin for 'with'.

There are many villages in England which are named 'something cum somewhere', and they liberally appear on road-signs etc. It arises where two parishes, at some point in history, have been merged.

'Chorlton cum Hardy' is nowadays a well-known suburb of Manchester.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use "extra", "in addition to", "also", "combined with". As in '*bedroom and study*' or '*bedroom cum study*'.